# Array Comparison doesnt work but why?

Tags: java, arrays, compare

Hello i created 2 arrays, that i know have the same type int, and could have the same values, both consists randomly created numbers in a special intervall.

Now i want to compare the numbers of one array to the numbers of the other one and have a int counting how much often there is the same number in both of the arrays.

```
Array1 [1,5,7,8,11,15]
Array2 [15,4,3,2,7,20]
```

I expect the counter to be 2. Becasue there are 2 matches 15 and 7 but with my code i always get 0. Why that?

```
for(int i= 0; i<t.length; i++){

     if(t[0]==zd[i]){
         counter = counter +1;
     } else if(t[1]==zd[i]){
         counter = counter +1;
     } else if(t[2]==zd[i]){
         counter = counter +1;
     } else if(t[3]==zd[i]){
         counter = counter +1;
     } else if(t[4]==zd[i]){
         counter = counter +1;
     } else if(t[5]==zd[i]){
         counter = counter +1;
     }

     System.out.println(counter);    

}
```

Could it be because i initiated the counter with 0 outside the for?

Comment: Can you show how your arrays are defined ?

Comment: Are you sure they are `int[]` and not `Integer[]`?

Answer (score 1):

Use a nested loop. The outside loop will loop over each of the first arrays values, and for each first array value, loop over all of the second array values. If you find a match, increment the counter.

```
    int [] arr1 = {1,5,7,8,11,15};
    int [] arr2 = {15,4,3,2,7,20};

    int matches = 0;
    for(Integer arrayOneValue : arr1){
        for(Integer arrayTwoValue : arr2){
            if(arrayOneValue.equals(arrayTwoValue)){
                matches++;
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println("Matches: " + matches);
```

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be some issue with your array declaration.I tried this and got expected results.

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String a1[]) {
        int[] t={1,5,7,8,11,15};
        int[] zd={15,4,3,2,7,20};
        int counter =0;
        for(int i= 0; i<t.length; i++){



            if(t[0]==zd[i]){

                     counter = counter +1;
                 }else if(t[1]==zd[i]){

                     counter = counter +1;
                 }else if(t[2]==zd[i]){
                     counter = counter +1;
                 }else if(t[3]==zd[i]){
                     counter = counter +1;
                 }else if(t[4]==zd[i]){
                     counter = counter +1;
                 }else if(t[5]==zd[i]){
                     counter = counter +1;
                 }   

             } 
        System.out.println(counter);

    }
}
```

Output

```
2
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a **nested loop** to loop through the second array. Plus, you don't need all those if statements, one will do :

```
int counter = 0;

int [] t = {1,5,7,8,11,15};
int [] zd = {15,4,3,2,7,20};

for(int i= 0; i<t.length; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < zd.length; j++) {
        if(t[i]==zd[j]){
            counter++; // counter = counter + 1; 
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int counter = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < t.length; i++)
{
  for(int j = 0; i < zd.length, j++)
  {
     if(t[i] == zd[j]) counter++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the arrays could be of type Integer[], this could easily be solved using CollectionUtils.

```
    Integer[] array1 = {1,5,7,8,11,15};
    Integer[] array2 = {15,4,3,2,7,20};

    System.out.println(CollectionUtils.intersection(Arrays.asList(array1), Arrays.asList(array2)).size());
```